# How can I unlock my Samsung Galaxy Ace?

Tags: sim-unlocking, samsung-galaxy-ace

I have just purchased a Galaxy Ace locked to a specific carrier. I was wondering if it is possible to unlock the phone for free without having to pay for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as with many of the Galaxy devices it appears that the unlock code is actually stored on the device and easily accessible (as long as you have root access).

[This XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1335548) should guide you through it.  Note of course that it might not work and you could brick your device by rooting, in addition to voiding the warranty.  In my experience the Galaxy devices are hard to brick and unlikely to be problematic.

Comment: thanks!!! you saved me 100 dollars. Took me about one hour.

Comment: @dgamma3 Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

Free methods to unlock Samsung Galaxy Ace are not safe ,They may cause permanent damage to the phone . To unlock your phone safely and easily ,you can use Unlock codes .You can get the unlock code from your service provider or from online vendors like [SuperUnlockCodes.com](http://www.superunlockcodes.com/samsung-galaxy-ace/rs16wp9/) .

Answer (score 0):

I have done lots of reading and it is possible to unlock the phone for free.

But personally not being technically minded I didn't feel confident myself, so I sent my phone to a guy on [ebay](http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/221232033776) who did the following for a reasonable value:

- unlocked
- rooted
- installed a better ROM (Looks like Jellybean on the Galaxy S2)

and also, fixed my low memory issues using ***appstosd***.